# iphone- a custom delegate method not getting called

Tags: iphone, delegates

I am trying to update db when the app the online, it is working fine, i want to reload the tableview once the update is finished. I am using a custom delegate to make that happen, but on my tableviewcontroller, the delegate method is never called.

.h

```
@protocol DBJsonUpdateComplete
  -(void) updateFinished;
@end

@interface UpdateDbJson : NSOperation {
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSURLConnection *connect;
    id <DBJsonUpdateComplete> delegate;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id <DBJsonUpdateComplete> delegate;

@end
```

.m i call when update is finished.

```
@synthesize delegate;

[delegate updateFinished];
```

In my taleviewcontroller

.h

```
UITableViewController <DBJsonUpdateComplete>
```

.m

```
- (void) updateFinished  {
    [self addReloadButton:YES];
}
```

but the updateFinished never gets called, everything is working fine except the delegate method.

am i not doing it correctly? please help? how can i debug ?

Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you assign the delegate? i mean...please check that first...

```
updateDbJsonObject.delegate = self;
```

Comment: you are welcome...silly issue, i still missed that...

whatever cheers :)